# On square roots and Geometric means

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a$ and $b$ be two negative integers, say $-4$ and $-1$

So

$$\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{-4\cdot(-1)}= + 2 $$

But then again,
$\sqrt{ab}$ is the geometric mean between $a$ and $b$, so it is supposed to lie between $a$ and $b$ that is between $-4$ and $-1$.

These two statements/results contradict each other...

Obviously i have messed up either of these two concepts and would be grateful if someone  could help me clear the same.. thank you

Comment: $a$ and $b$ must be non-negative

Comment: would you please elaborate?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, I think the geometric mean applies as long as the signs of $a$ and $b$ are identical.

Comment: @ZainPatel, like any other mean, for GM we have $\min(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\le GM(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\le \max(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. If you want to use negative numbers, put modulus, and OP was right: $\min(|-1|, |-4|)\le 2\le \max(|-1|, |-4|)$

Comment: This is a good question. Endorsed. I think that the definition of geometric mean is just wrong or just practical. People just will justify what they read on books but in reality the question is very good.

Answer (score 1):

I always saw the geometric mean something similar to a distance formula: it is supposed to give you the distance of the mean, not the actual position of it per say (however when it is positive you get the position and distance :P ).

Think of it this way, if $\sqrt{(4)\cdot(1)} = 2$ and $\sqrt{(-4)\cdot(-1)} = 2$ then it must be the distance of the mean from 0 rather than the actual position of the mean itself (Even with imaginary numbers, you always refer to the roots using a positive i, never a negative i)